# Why the labels/buttons（like run/save, etc.） above the google earth engine code editor are grey and not working?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Why the labels/buttons（like run/save, etc.） above the google earth engine code editor are grey and not working?[image: I opened Google Earth Engine and I can edit my code, but I can't save or run the code. Also, the docs can't be seen]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably, you have a slow internet connection. Reset GEE tab in your browser until these buttons appear functional.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the Earth Engine Code Editor has not yet successfully connected to the Earth Engine API server. (You'll also see that the Docs tab is missing most of its documentation, too, since that's downloaded as part of the same process.)

It might be a temporary problem with the service or with your internet connection, or if a firewall is blocking access. You should approach this problem as you would any other where a web page isn't fully loading.

Comment: Thank you very much, I restarted the computer and it’s fixed